# Djando UNIQUE constraint failed: rec.id

Tags: python, django

Переопределил метод save() в модели, и теперь когда изменяю запись в админке, то выпадает ошибка "UNIQUE constraint failed: rec.id".

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.slug = slugify(self.title)
    super(Post, self).save(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

Ругается на последнюю строку, как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы в последней строке с количеством self не напутали?
Кажетс, надо так:

```
super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```